# What is the use of pagination while Recyclerview itself recycle views?

Tags: android

I am confused regarding using pagination in android Resyclerview, they say if Recyclerview data got large it is better to use pagoination. Doesn't Recyclerview load data as much as it is visible on the screen? Then why use pagination?

My Recyclerview works but I don't know wether to use pagination. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is used to get large number of data from the server it self, recycler view is the component that loads data in the form of cell. but to getting data from the server it will take time. so reduce the api call timing and also to manage in proper way from the api side we require pagination. pagination is different and recycler view is different. Pagination is technic to get data and recyclerview is the component to load data.

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: I have local sqlite database and data size is around 50 MB to 200 MB,  so in my situation is it  better to use pagination? Or pagination is good only to get data from the server?

Comment: I hope you are storing data in form of location in sqlite right? if you are storing location or path of the image or video and data is less like less then 300 or something then you can ignore pagination but if you are storing data in form of bitmap or something and also large number of data is there like 500+ somewhere then pagination is good to use

Comment: what ever  we are taking data from server or sqlite if fetching data taking time then we can split them and use pagination for that. and rest recycler will work as it is with pagination or without pagination